# Writing a text with scatter plot points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Ok, this is a bit of a funky idea, but is it possible to generate a dataset of points that, when plotted, display a desired text? I remember seeing this somewhere, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It's totally possible. But please sketch the idea a bit more in detail and best provide insight into what the input data would be like and how you imagine the output to look like.

Comment: So my idea would be to give the function a string, for example "Hello!" and the function would return a 3D array. When this 3D array would be plotted (of course in 3D) , it would spell Hello! with the plot points. The function should also allow you to choose how many points it generates.

Comment: I don't think I understand this. What would determine the coordinates if they are not provided by the user?

Comment: The shape of each letter.

Comment: There are much easier ways to display a text in a plot, what is the data needed for?

Comment: Ok, maybe I was not clear enough. I want a function that generates something like this, but in 3D, if I give it the string "HI"

https://s22.postimg.cc/fstnnzf9d/mypic.png